# How to include a row with subtotals by second level group in Einstein Analytics using SAQL?

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard, saql, group-by

I would like to add a subtotal row at the bottom of a compare table in an Einstein Analytics dashboard. The table is made up of sums of measures grouped by two dimensions. The subtotals needed are those of the second group, such that this table

```
Group1     Group2   A   B
X           M       8   10
            N       5   100
Y           M       3   50
            N       7   200
```

will generate the subtotals

```
subtotals   M      11   60
            N      12   300
```

and add them at the bottom of the table.

Einstein Analytics dashboards do not appear to have this functionality. Is there a way to do this with SAQL?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a second subquery such as:

```
q2 = group q by Group2;
q2 = foreach q2 generate
    "subtotals" as Group1,
    Group2,
    count() as A,
    sum(DataXY) as B;
```

Afterwards union your 2 queries together.

```
result = union q, q2;
```